# Illusion of moving Cursor

Tags: javascript, image, position, cursor, location

Is it possible to make an image appear at cursor location (for example, a cursor image) then hide the original (`cursor:none;`) then make the image move! Giving the illusion that the pointer is moving by itself, then making the cursor appear where the image of the cursor went. Then make the image disappear. I'm not sure about making the cursor appear

I read that it is impossible to move the cursor with Javascript for security reasons, so I was thinking of just creating the illusion of it wich is fine for my purposes. An yes or no will suffice! (so i can go foward) Didn't find much about making images appear at cursor location! :P

Comment: It's possible, you should use absolute positioned div holding the cursor image and move that around (by using mousemove event handler for example), in combination with cursor:none of course..

Comment: The image movement wouldn't be made by the user but by programed transition/movement. So point is for the 'cursor' (image of it) to appear to move by iteslef (like some ghost controlling it!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`An yes or no will suffice!`

Yes [image]

Okay, so let's answer a bit more in-depth...

We make a div (`#bar`) where we want the "custom" pointer to be in and on which we'll hide the actual pointer:

```html
<div id="bar">
    <div id="pointer"></div>
</div>
```

Set `cursor` to `none` to hide the actual pointer, set up an image in `#pointer` to act as substitute:

```css
body {
    padding:50px;
}
#bar {
    background-color: green;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    cursor: none;
}
#pointer {
    position: absolute;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background-image:url('//i.imgur.com/uKc3VMy.png');
}
```

Add a little javascript (I took the jQuery route, but it's perfectly possible using vanilla JS as well) to move the image around acting as pointer:

```js
$("#bar").mousemove(function (e) {
    $('#pointer').offset({
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY
    })
});
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/e9BXg/1/

Comment: To give illusion of moving pointer - 1st: Make pointer image appear where real pointer was. 2nd: Make real pointer disappear. 3rd: Make image of pointer move to programmed coordinates. So the user will be like "wtf is this?" (so it will look as if the pointer is moving by itself) In your example it's the user who is controlling the pointer when it shouldn't! - Although your code did help in what I needed help for!

Comment: `In your example it's the user who is controlling the pointer when it shouldn't!` Ooooh! You wanted teh codez for your **complete** problem instead of a pointer (pun intended) in the right direction! Why didn't you say so? */me mumbles something about 'Give a man a fish, feed him for a day. Teach a man how to fish, feed him for a lifetime'*. `Although your code did help in what I needed help for!` Ah, well! There you go then! Next time I'd be happy to provide you with the perfect, complete, solution. Just make sure you send me your address so I can send you an invoice for my time.